# MailCore2 Reply / Forward

Tags: ios, mailcore2

I'm using MailCore2 and everything looks perfect when I'm sending a new email, but now I'm trying to understand how to set an email like Reply or Forward.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you taken a look at RFC 822 sources of emails? Taking a look at RFC 822 will be useful anyway.

Comment: No I didn't read that, i will take a look but how that part will help me? Thanks!

Comment: When I tried to use -[MCOMessageHeader replyHeaderWithExcludedRecipients:]
or -[MCOMessageHeader replyAllHeaderWithExcludedRecipients:] I'm getting an error like "sender is not defined", but if i remove this header from the builder the sending is perfect but no reply type

Comment: What component send you an error message?

Comment: I fixed the problem, I was setting all the attributes (to, subject, from) and then i was getting the header for reply. Now everything looks perfect so thanks for you help. Do you know what i need to use to mark an email like forward? in my opinion its exactly the same email that i'm getting but adding "FWD:" to the subject... what do you think? @DinhViêtHoà

Comment: You can match what other email clients are doing.

Comment: Hi, I am looking some sample source to develop the same features. please check my query and help me.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981583/implementing-reply-reply-all-forward-features-using-mailcore2-imap-email-ios-l